# HybridGraphics AMD/INTEL doesn't work

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, xorg

Another trouble with HybridGraphics. I didn't find an issue for the moment. 
I read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics but no way. I would like to be as precise as possible to describe the trouble and my searches

Tanks for your help because I'm lost for 10 days.

**Computer** : Dell Inspiron 5559, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz

**OS** : LinuxMint 17.2 based on Ubuntu 14.04

**Kernel** : 4.2.3

```
lshw -enable pci -class display
*-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ   
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: Intel Corporation
   fabriquant: Intel Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 2
   information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   ressources: mémoire:d1000000-d1ffffff mémoire:b0000000-bfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64)
*-display
   description: Display controller
   produit: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
   fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 81
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   ressources: irq:125 mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0000000-d003ffff portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:d0040000-d005ffff




inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 1916 
       X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: fbdev,ati,radeon (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: intel Resolution: 1920x1080@77.0hz 
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits) GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
```

What is the meaning of **NON RECLAME** ?

Why **FAILED** appears ?

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
```

Only Intel appears but not Amd

```
grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*
/boot/config-4.2.3-040203-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
```

Switcheroo is enabled but **/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch** is missing

**Xorg.conf** file is missing in **/etc/X11/Xsession.d/**

At boot, i've seen **radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22)**

**xserver-xorg-video-ati** v 1:7.3.0 (open driver) is running instead of **fglrx-updates** v 2:15.200 or **fglrx** v 2:15.200 (the computer freezes if i use these 2 last drivers)

```
grep /drivers/ /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    52.539] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    52.539] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    52.539] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    52.539] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    52.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    52.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    52.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    52.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    52.540] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    52.541] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    52.541] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
```

Thanks for your Help. I hope that LinuxMint 17.3 will fix this trouble.

Comment: There is a bug in kernel 4.2 preventing the init of the radeon driver. Good starting point would be bisect the kernel to find out last good kernel version which works with the graphic switch.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem with a similar radeon graphic card.

i installed the mainline kernel version 4.6 from here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/

Here is a guide for the installation:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Verifying_the_mainline_build_binaries

After booting the new kernel, i tested the card with the following command, and the changing to the radeon graphic card was working:

$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info

(have posted this hint there too: [16.04 - Radeon R7 M260 errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778205/16-04-radeon-r7-m260-errors/780515#780515))