# 16.04 - Radeon R7 M260 errors

Tags: graphics, 16.04, radeon, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 on my HP [Elitebook 840 G2](http://www8.hp.com/at/de/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7343202#!tab=specs) and got several error messages because of my [Radeon R7 M260X](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/notebook/r7-m200).

```
dpkg -l | grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                                        2.4.67-1                                            amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                                   1.1.0-1                                             amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

I also looked into the [driver features](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) though i dont know what to read out of them.

Errors in dmesg:

```
[   15.188843] radeon 0000:04:00.0: WB enabled
[   15.188846] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc00
[   15.188848] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc04
[   15.188849] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc08
[   15.188851] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc0c
[   15.188852] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc10
[   15.190426] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002435a18
[   15.291338] radeon 0000:04:00.0: VCE init error (-110).
[   15.363600] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.363602] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.363606] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.420411] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   15.422122] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.423579] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.484757] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.486214] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.517056] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   15.792955] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   15.792963] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   15.792968] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   15.792979] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 5 usecs
[   15.792987] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 5 usecs
[   15.796040] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   15.969028] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   15.969035] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   15.969071] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   15.969100] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   15.969128] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   15.969156] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   15.969184] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   15.997342] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   16.133308] input: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer as /devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input24
[   16.185402] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   19.379164] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   19.379194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[   26.117646] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ring 5 stalled for more than 10000msec
[   26.118368] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000002 last fence id 0x0000000000000004 on ring 5)
[   26.118479] [drm:uvd_v1_0_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait failed (-35).
[   26.119262] [drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on ring 5 (-35).
[   28.617118] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   28.622099] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[   28.653735] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2593994008 Hz
[   28.653738] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)
[   28.658096] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   28.661211] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   28.666592] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   28.668608] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   33.034688] wlo1: authenticate with 0c:27:24:e0:4b:4f
[   33.040075] wlo1: send auth to 0c:27:24:e0:4b:4f (try 1/3)
[   33.055172] wlo1: authenticated
[   33.057851] wlo1: associate with 0c:27:24:e0:4b:4f (try 1/3)
[   33.061858] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 0c:27:24:e0:4b:4f (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[   33.062970] wlo1: associated
[   33.063011] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   33.254016] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: AT
[   33.254020] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[   33.254021] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   33.254024] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.254026] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.254028] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   33.254030] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   33.254032] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.256082] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 18 dBm as advertised by 0c:27:24:e0:4b:4f
[   34.168377] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:9c98 = 5323c42/0
[   34.168382] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   34.175492] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
[   34.175594] radeon 0000:04:00.0: WB enabled
[   34.175596] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc00
[   34.175597] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc04
[   34.175599] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc08
[   34.175600] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc0c
[   34.175601] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88044519dc10
[   34.177137] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002435a18
[   34.277967] radeon 0000:04:00.0: VCE init error (-110).
[   34.741671] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   34.741713] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   34.741719] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   34.741729] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[   34.741737] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
[   34.917798] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   34.918003] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   34.918039] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   34.918070] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   34.918108] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   34.918138] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   34.918343] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   45.066399] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ring 5 stalled for more than 10000msec
[   45.066402] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000004 last fence id 0x0000000000000006 on ring 5)
[   45.066449] [drm:uvd_v1_0_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait failed (-35).
[   45.066469] [drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on ring 5 (-35).
[   45.497026] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[   46.925039] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   46.925046] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   46.925051] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

I also uploaded the [full output](https://gist.github.com/JuHwon/a076b7e7d16778f13879bdc4abbd63ed) of my dmesg.

lspci:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal PRO [Radeon R7 M260]
```

xrandr:

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x6e cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 9 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x41 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:04:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x41 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:04:00.0
```

When i type `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` i get a bunch of errors too like `radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer` and `Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same problem with a similar radeon graphic card.

i installed the mainline kernel version 4.6 from here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/

Here is a guide for the installation:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Verifying_the_mainline_build_binaries

After booting the new kernel, i tested the card with the following command, and the changing to the radeon graphic card was working:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```

Comment: worked fine. now the only remaining issue is the VCE error. Though it seems this is not a problem.

Comment: I've been having a similar problem with my Radeon HD 6870 since updating from 14.04 to 16.04. When running Kodi and playing particular video files the graphics will freeze at particular moments of the video. It plays OK with smplayer. If I skip that bit in Kodi the rest plays fine. With 16.04 stock it'd freeze the graphics totally and I could do nothing. I could log in via SSH and kill kodi which would zombie and I still couldn't use the machine (or reboot). I installed the oibaf drivers and latest mainline kernel and still get the freeze, but now after 10 seconds or so it recovers itself.